# ExtJS drag event listeners work differently on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have added an input field to Window's title bar (header). On Chrome selecting and editing the input field works, and I can still drag the window around. On Firefox I can drag the window around the viewport, but I am unable to select the input field and edit it. How should I correct this code so that it would work on both browsers?

Quick'n'dirty demonstration of the problem:

```
Ext.define('Demo.DemoWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'demowindow',

    height: 300,
    width: 400,
    title: 'Window',
    autoShow: true,
    items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text : 'Press!',
            listeners: {
              click: function() {
               var win = this.up('window');
               var header = win.getHeader();
               header.setTitle('');

               var killDrag = false;
               var dragEvent = win.dd.on({
                 beforedragstart: function(dd, e) {
                   if (killDrag) {
                     return false;
                   }
                 }
               });

               var field = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
                 name: 'Title',
                 allowBlank: false,
                 value: 'Type here something!',
                 listeners: {
                   el: {
                     delegate: 'input',
                     mouseout: function() {
                       killDrag = false;
                     },
                     mouseenter: function() {
                       killDrag = true;
                     }
                   }
                 }
                });

                header.insert(0, field);

              }
            }
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Demo',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'absolute',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'demowindow',
                    x: 20,
                    y: 20,
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `mouseover` event instead of `mouseenter` seems to work well with both.

Comment: Interesting. I'm questioning myself though - should I have just tried mouse* events in order... Any reason why you found this answer so easily?

Comment: I saw the `mouseenter` event was not firing in FF, and [MDN on `mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) suggests that `mouseover` behaves the way we need. A quick test confirmed it... Do you know if it works in IE?

Comment: I don't have access to IE at this moment. I will get around testing all I've done with IE 10 some day now. Not expecting much for the older versions at least.